# Keras plot_model input and output shape only question mark

Tags: keras, yolo

I'm trying to code YOLOV1 in Keras, and I use the VGG16 which accepts (224,224,3) while the input is (448, 448, 3) (that's the size used by the authors) so I added a Conv2D and a MaxPooling layer to convert 448 to 224. However, when I use plot_model the input and output shapes of Conv and MaxPooling layers in the middle are all question mark (?).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   base_model = VGG16(
        input_shape=backbone_img_shape,
        # input_shape=img_shape,
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet')
    # pdb.set_trace()
    img_input = Input(shape=img_shape)
    arch = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu') (img_input)
    arch = layers.MaxPooling2D() (arch)
    for i, layer in enumerate(base_model.layers[2:]):
        arch = layer(arch)
    # arch = base_model(img_input)
    arch = layers.Flatten() (arch)
    arch = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu') (arch)
    arch = layers.Dropout(0.5) (arch)
    arch = layers.Dense((grid_num_per_axis**2)*(num_bbox_per_grid*5 + n_cls)) (arch)
    arch = layers.Reshape(
        (grid_num_per_axis, grid_num_per_axis, num_bbox_per_grid*5 + n_cls)) (arch)
    model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=arch)
    model.summary()
    # pdb.set_trace()
    model.compile(
        # optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9),
        optimizer='adam',
        loss=yolov1_loss)
    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='haha.png', show_shapes=True)
```

where backbone_img_shape=(224,224,3) and img_shape=(448,448,3). I think there is something wrong because, for example max_pooling2d layer had (?, 224, 224, 64) size but the later layers should have had something similar instead they had (?). Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: You should ask a question directly, to me its not clear what you want help with.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I think that the question marks show that something is wrong with my model initialization

Comment: No, the question marks are about variable size in that dimension, I do not see anything wrong (and you did not ask a question)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I think there is something wrong because, for example max_pooling2d layer had (?, 224, 224, 64) size but the later layers should have had something similar instead they had (?)

Comment: Its beter to use model.summary() to see the structure of your model